# Unmet Dependencies and Broken Packages

Tags: apt, steam

When attempting to install Steam, I get this error message:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I've searched through other forums and they all suggest essentially the same things, all of which I have tried, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem to install steam and hace happened to many users.
To install steam you need to install some 32-bit libraries 
Run the following command:

sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386

Then install steam, everything should work fine.

Comment: I tried installing the required packages, but it says they are already installed.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed and etc...

Comment: Attempting to install any of the dependencies yields this error: E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.